# What does ２世帯５人 mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, counters

> 盛岡市によりますと、午後７時半現在、**２世帯５人**が近くの児童センターで一夜を明かす予定だということです。

Is it 2 families that have no link composed of a total of 5 persons or a normal family(3 or 4 members) + the grandparent(s) (1 or 2 member(s)) ?

Comment: 世帯 is a whole word that means household/family no ?
"火事で４世帯が焼死した。
Four families were killed in the fire."

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the context of [the story](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20180203/k10011313991000.html) it can be assumed that they were from two separate households simply located in near proximity to the source of the explosion, for a total of 5 people. There is, however, no specific detail as to the makeup of these families and their relationship to one another (as this is likely not relevant to the story and in interest of privacy).